# character_set_filesystem not present in show variables

Tags: mysql, character-encoding

I'm a little worried about the absence of this variable when I execute the `show variables` command. This is what I get when I execute `show variables like 'char%'`:

```
character_set_client        utf8
character_set_connection    utf8
character_set_database      utf8
character_set_results       utf8
character_set_server        utf8
character_set_system        utf8
character_sets_dir          /usr/share/mysql/charsets/
```

I wonder why this is happening. What does it mean? can I just add it to the `my.cnf` file?

Thank you...

Edit: Sorry, I recently noted that I didn't specify which variable we're talking about (though I said it in the title). The variable is `character_set_filesystem`. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_character-set-filesystem

```
Version Introduced  5.1.6
```

So most likely you have mysql < 5.1.6

Comment: Indeed! I'm using 4.1.22 but was worried about why everybody listed it! Thank you!